# jquery doesn't work on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var h = 600;
var w = 1024;
var x = (screen.width - w) / 2;
var y = (screen.height - h) / 2;
var commonWindow = window.open(url, "",  "screenX="+x+",screenY="+y+",left="+x+",top="+y+",width="+w+",height="+h);
var bankCdOpener = $("input[name=bankCd]", commonWindow.opener.document).val();
var branchCdOpener = $("input[name=branchCd]", commonWindow.opener.document).val();
$(commonWindow.document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=bankCd]", commonWindow.document).val(bankCdOpener);
    $("input[name=branchCd]", commonWindow.document).val(branchCdOpener);
});
```

In the new open window, I can get the values of bankCd and branchCd from opener window when I run it on IE.

But it doesn't work on Chrome.
Here is the code, please help me.

Comment: What is purpose of setting `context` at `var bankCdOpener = $("input[name=bankCd]", commonWindow.opener.document).val()`?

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at plnkr https://plnkr.co? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Maybe the window is not opened yet when you're trying to get some references to objects the window contains. Put all related code into the ready handler.

Comment: Title is not matched with problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `load` event of opened `window`

```
commonWindow.onload = function() {
  $("input[name=bankCd]", commonWindow.document).val(bankCdOpener);
  $("input[name=branchCd]", commonWindow.document).val(branchCdOpener);
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/xcMP7zQ5g6gEfJJu0On7?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, guest271314. I tried, and it works very well for Chrome now. But it doesn't work for IE now. Could you give an another advice for this?

Comment: Cannot offer a suggestion for ie.  You can use both patterns.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am considering. Anyway, thank you so much